# how to include spring RESTful service to my existing Struts2.0 project

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, struts2

I was trying to implement spring RESTful service to my existing struts project, but not able to complete the same.i added spring rest service but when I tried to run my existing application,it does not work..below is my complete code for the same.i have all the files defined below ,please check and help on the same.

below is my  Web.xml file

```
<!-- spring context config-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml; classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- spring listner-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/webmvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>     
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/showAllgrants/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <!-- listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.nea.web.struts.ContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener-->

    <!--servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.abc.efg.web.AppResources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>validate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet-->

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/NotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/NotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/Error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

below is my spring  webmvc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


          <!--  
            Enables automatic mapping of fund objects to and from JSON  
      -->  
      <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
      <!--  
            Setup spring to pull in @Controller, @RequestMapping, etc Configuration scans specified packages  
            for classes configured as Spring managed beans and automatically sets up objects annotated with  
            @Controller, @Service etc.  
      -->  
      <context:component-scan base-package="org.web.struts.uniservs" />  

      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />  
      <!--  
            Configures view for returning JSON to the client  
      -->  
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">  
           <property name="contentType" value="text/plain"/>  
      </bean>  
      <!--  
            maps handler methods based on HTTP paths
      -->  
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">      
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <!-- Default converters -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

   <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="/*">strutsWrappingController</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="strutsWrappingController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController" scope="singleton">

<property name="servletClass">
    <value>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</value>
</property>
<property name="servletName">
    <value>action</value>
</property>
<property name="initParameters">
    <props>
        <prop key="config">/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

    <bean id="empService"
        class="org.nea.spring.services.implementations.employee"/>  
    <bean id="iaUtilitiesService"
        class="org.nea.spring.services.implementations"/>

</beans>
```

below is my struts TestAction.java

```
@Controller
public class TestAction   extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ServletContextAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6274330790290034472L;

@RequestMapping(value="/showAllgrants/{year}/{status}/{stateId}",
            method=RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public String showAllgrants(@PathVariable String year,@PathVariable String status,@PathVariable String stateId) {
        /*commented to test restful service
        User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null) {
            return LOGIN;
        }
        */
        List<UniServGrantInfo> grantInfoList = new ArrayList<UniServGrantInfo>();
        //String year = request.getParameter("year");
        //String status = request.getParameter("status");
        //String stateId = request.getParameter("stateId");

        grantInfoList = uniservService.showAllgrants("ITSMAXK", year, status, stateId);
            /* commented to test restful service
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(grantInfoList);

        JSONWrapper jsonWrap = new JSONWrapper();
        jsonWrap.setObjects(grantInfoList.toArray());
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonWrap);
        String jsonString = convertJSONObjectToString(jsonObject);
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.toString().getBytes());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("grantInfoList", grantInfoList);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("year", year);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("status", status);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("stateId", stateId);
        */
        return SUCCESS;

    }
}
```

below is my   struts-config.xml file

```
<action name="showAllgrants"
            class=""
            method="showAllgrants">
            <result type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
                <param name="contentType">text/json</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?